# React data export to excel (xlsx)

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I want to export JSON data to a excel file but the format should be 'xlsx'. I could not find any source in react to do that. I found this link but we can not export as xlsx format by using this.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-json-data-to-excel-in-react-application/
Please help me.

Comment: Why do you need XLSX? Any application that accepts XLSX should also accept CSV. Does your JSON hold stringified versions of spreadsheet-specific data (e.g. formulae)?

Comment: @jsejcksn Actually, the client needs to export the file as xlsx format.  This file doesn't require to import in any application. It is just a view file.